# How do I convert a dictionary with coordinates and frequencies to a matrix?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, dictionary, plot

I have a dictionary that looks like:

`data = {(-1.0, 4.0): 1, (2.0, 2.0): 12, (3.0, 1.0): 8}`

And I want to make a matrix that looks like:

```
[[0. 0. 0. 0. 0.]
 [1. 0. 0. 0. 0.]
 [0. 0. 0. 12. 0.]
 [0. 0. 0. 0. 8.]
 [0. 0. 0. 0. 0.]]
```

where every key in the dictionary is 'coordinate' in my matrix (starting from the bottom left corner) and the limits of the axis are defined by me (xlim: -3, 13, ylim: -6, 8) *not shown*.

I've tried to attempt this by doing:

```
matrix = np.zeros((5,5))
for (x, y), z in data.items():
    x = int(x)
    y = int(y)

    matrix[y,x] = z
```

But I am getting errors with negative dimensions.

My ultimate goal is to plot my dictionary as some sort of histogram where the coordinates are x,y and the dictionary values (freq) are my z dimensions or the 'depth'.

Comment: convert dict into pandas df and plot

Comment: Your code works fine on my computer

Comment: Can you "normalise" your coordinates? That is, if minimum x is -3, then add 3 to *every* x-co, thus moving your origin. Or something like x = int(x + abs(minx)).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Similar to what's already been suggested, "move" the matrix into the positive region and then locate coordinates using an x and y offset:

```
import numpy as np
data = {(-1.0, 4.0): 1, (2.0, 2.0): 12, (3.0, 1.0): 8}
x_offset = 3
y_offset = 6
mat = np.zeros((17, 15))
for (x, y), z in data.items():
    mat[int(y + y_offset), int(x + x_offset)] = z
```

**Edit**

Ok I think this is what you had in mind (I'll assume negative values are present in both the x and y coordinates):

If you want to hardcode the ranges for x and y values (xlim: -3, 13, ylim: -6, 8):

```
x_min, x_max = -3, 13
y_min, y_max = -6, 8
```

Or to determine them from the data:

```
x_min = min([x for (x, y), z in data.items()])
y_min = min([y for (x, y), z in data.items()])
x_max = max([x for (x, y), z in data.items()])
y_max = max([y for (x, y), z in data.items()])
```

Then use:

```
x_offset = abs(x_min)
y_offset = abs(y_min)

mat = np.zeros((y_max + y_offset + 1, x_max + x_offset + 1))    # (Row, column) becomes (y, x)

for (x, y), z in data.items():
    print(x, y)
    mat[int(y + y_offset), int(x + x_offset)] = z

pd.DataFrame(mat, columns=range(x_min, x_max + 1), 
                  index=range(y_min, y_max + 1))
```

Then plot using:

```
plt.imshow(mat, origin='lower', extent=[x_min, x_max + 1, 
                                        y_min, y_max + 1])
```

Comment: And 16 = maxX - minX = 13 - (-3)

Comment: I like this answer. However, when I ```print (mat)``` the value '12' (as an example) is not actually located in position (2,2) but rather in position (9,11). When I use ```plt.imshow(mat)``` the y-axis doesn't start from 0 either.

Comment: Tried that @tom but the actual points are not in the right positions. Will try the new edit!

Comment: I also want to know - when using ```imshow(mat)``` for the new edit, the x,y axis are from 0 upwards and not my defined axis (xlim: -3, 13, ylim: -6, 8) ie how would i plot the df? **edit** i used ```extent=[-3,14, -6,8]``` to view the range

Comment: How can I make the x and y offset, and the number of 0's in the array arbitrary and dependant on the data?

Comment: @HajSai Something like `x_min = min([x for (x, y), z in data.items()]),
y_min = min([y for (x, y), z in data.items()]),
x_max = max([x for (x, y), z in data.items()]),
y_max = max([y for (x, y), z in data.items()])` would help, and then set `x_offset = x_min` and `y_offset = y_min`

Comment: Thank you. Are the numpy values to make an empty matrix (15 and 17) fixated?

Comment: No problem. In my previous comment it should be `x_offset = abs(x), y_offset = abs(y)`. If you want the dimensions of your empty matrix to match the range of your input data: `np.zeros((y_max + y_offset + 1, x_max + x_offset + 1))`. All of this assumes that there are indeed negative numbers present in both the x and y coordinates (which might well be worth checking).

Comment: Should it be: x_offset = int(abs(x)) or x_offset = int(abs(x_min))? Also, do the df ranges change too? Would be grateful if you can update the final answer!

Comment: Yes it should, apologies that was a typo. Will do.

Answer (score 0):

numpy allows negative indexing
then you can use:

`np.rot90(matrix, 1)`

that's moves [0,0] to the left bottom

Answer (score 0):

Numpy will not give error on negative index but it will index it from last which is not what you intended. 
You are choosing wrong dimension for your matrix. Following code calculates size of matrix to fit all your locations then shift your location coordinates to fit in the matrix, in this case by -3 and -6

```
xlim = (-3, 13)
ylim = (-6,8)

# your array dimension must be
dim = xlim[1] - xlim[0], ylim[1]-ylim[0]

matrix = np.zeros(dim)

for (x, y), z in data.items():
    # this will also work for +ve lower limit
    x_new = int(x-xlim[0])
    y_new = int(y-ylim[0])

    # negetive sign because we want the index to start from bottom left
    matrix[-x_new, y_new] = z

print(matrix)


# if you want to remove rows and colums with all zeros
new_matrix = matrix[np.sum(matrix, axis=1)>0]
new_matrix = new_matrix[:,np.sum(matrix, axis=0)>0].copy()
print("\n",new_matrix)
```

Comment: I am a little confused because when I ```print(matrix)``` say position (2.0,2.0) is not actually indexed in 2.0,2.0 in the array, and its rather in (9,5)..

Comment: It is shifting the index, your xlim is -3 to 13 so your x coordinate at -3 is at index -1(last row) in matrix and 13 in you x coordinate is at index 0 in matrix. If you want to map 2,2 of your coordinate to 2,2 of the matrix what should be done to -2,-2 index?